Why is the von Neumann inequality not always fulfilled for n-tuples of commuting contractions? Why cant we just take the single dilations and get it?
Let $(T_1, \ldots, T_n)$ be an $n$-tuple of contractions in a Hilbert space $H$. We know, that for every single $T_i$, there exists a unitary operator $U_i$ in a Hilbert space $K_i$, such that $$T_i = P_{H} U_i |_{H}$$ This is called a unitary dilation. Of course, this theorem is also true if we take $T_i$ to the power of $n_i \in \mathbb{N}$, but for simplicity, we will ignore this notation in this thread.
Now, my question is the following:
If there exists a unitary dilation $U_i$ for every $T_i$, why can't we - in the case of $n$-tuples of commuting contractions, especially for $n\ge 3$ - simply take:
$$T_1 \ldots T_n = P_H (U_1 \ldots U_n) |_{H}$$
and by that obtain the von Neumann inequality, which is
$$\| p(T_1, \ldots, T_n) \| \le \sup_{(z_1, \ldots, z_n) \in \overline{\mathbb{D}^n}} |p(z_1, \ldots, z_n)|$$
and moreover obtain a dilation $(U_1, \ldots, U_n)$ on a Hilbert space $K := K_1 \cup \ldots \cup K_n$?
I know that there must be a very big flaw in my understanding, but I can't see where.
As I see it, there is no necessity for $U_1, \ldots U_n$ to be from the same Hilbert space. The polynomial $p$ does not care about it, as long as it's a unitary operator instead of a variable, you can apply the theorem that $\sigma(p(U)) = p(\sigma(U))$, the fact that the spectrum of a unitary operator is on the closed disk, and you finally obtain von Neumann's inequality.
And if you really do need to have the dilation to be in the same space, just define $K$ as the sum of the single dilation spaces $K_i$ and you get what you want.
It just seems "too easy to be true", and I know it's false due to counterexamples. But I just don't see the fundamental flaw in my understanding.
I hope you can help me out here. Maybe the problem lies in $U_i$ not necessarily commuting with each other, but this is unimportant for the von Neumann inequality?

I guess you need that $U_i$ commute

@RyszardSzwarc I think I know why now. It's because if $U_i$ don't commute, then it's in violation to $p$ being a polynomial of commuting variables.
